# Sturm-Liouville problem and Rayleigh quotient

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

I am having difficulty using the Rayleigh quotient to find the principal eigenvalue of the following SL problem

$$
u''(x) + (\lambda - x^{2})u(x) = 0\\
u'(0) = u(1) = 0
$$

To my understanding I need to find $u(x)$ first and then I can use the solution to find the principal eigenvalue.  However, solving the above SL problem has proven to be quite difficult as I need to use parabolic cylinder functions (according to wolfram).  I was curious if someone could shed some light on what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I doubt you can find $u(x)$ explicitly.

Comment: I'm only interested in finding an approximation for the principle eigenvalue.  I'm just confused about how one would use the rayleigh quotient given the additional terms..